# Why my function only works once (doing a document.write() job)?

Tags: javascript

In my html file, I have to display charts of different stocks in different places in the document. I wrote a javascript function source(ticker) to display the chart of "ticker". Here is the first part of my html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="CLP_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>The XXXXXX Daily</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function source(ticker)
{
                var d=new Date();
                var month=new Array(12);
                month[0]="01";
                month[1]="02";
                month[2]="03";
                month[3]="04";
                month[4]="05";
                month[5]="06";
                month[6]="07";
                month[7]="08";
                month[8]="09";
                month[9]="10";
                month[10]="11";
                month[11]="12";
                var startmonth;
                var startyear;
                var endmonth;
                endmonth=month[d.getMonth()];
                switch (endmonth) 
                    {
                    case "01":
                        startmonth="11";
                    case "02":
                        startmonth="12";
                    case "03":
                        startmonth="01";
                    case "04":
                        startmonth="02";
                    case "05":
                        startmonth="03";
                    case "06":
                        startmonth="04";
                    case "07":
                        startmonth="05";
                    case "08":
                        startmonth="06";
                    case "09":
                        startmonth="07";
                    case "10":
                        startmonth="08";
                    case "11":
                        startmonth="09";
                        startyear="2010";
                    case "12":
                        startmonth="10";
                        startyear="2010";
                    }
                var dateparam;
                dateparam=startyear+"-"+startmonth+"-"+d.getDate()+"&e="+d.getFullYear()+"-"+endmonth+"-"+d.getDate();
                var chartsource;
                chartsource="<img src=\"http://xxxxxx.com/chartsymbol_chart.php?s="+dateparam+"&m=line&dateby=1&bollinger=1&bollinger_day=20&sma=1&sma_day=20&chartsize=1&id="+ticker+"\"";
                source=chartsource+" align=\"top\" name=\"HSX\" height=\"250\" width=\"490\">";
                document.write(source);
}
            </script>
</head>

<body>
```

When I call the function, it works perfectly well.

```
<table width="980" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
                source("^vnindex");
            </script>
        </td>
        <td>
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
                source("^hastc");
            </script>
        </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but only the first time i.e ^vnindex chart show up, but ^hastc does not. At first, I thought it was because there is no ^hastc stock. But when I check with a simple html img tag, ^hastc did show up. And for the remaining part of the document, no chart shows up at all. It means that the function only work once.

I have no idea on how to fix it, and would appreciate it very much if you can help me with this.

Thanks
Toan Nguyen

Comment: Really should study up a bit on loops.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that document.write appends to the document only if the document is loading otherwise it will try and overwrite the contents of the page with whatever you specify!
Try insteand the DOM approach: document.appendChild( createElement("img") )....

Comment: Thanks. But I still can't make it work. Looping just creates images repeatedly in one place while I want it to display in different places in one html document. document.appendChild(createElement("img")) is a bit too complicated for me. I am just a beginner. Could anyone be a bit more specific? Thanks